# java client-server issue on client side (no System.out)

Tags: java, eclipse, console, client-server, client

probably a noobish Q:

So i made a very simple single-threaded server/client model. Now when i execute the program in the eclipse IDE it shows me System.out's of the server and not the ones from the client. 
When i press terminate, the System.out.println lines that were supposed to be generated by Client show up.

I'm struggling with this for days now.. Hopefully someone can help me out.

Thanks in advance!

SERVER:

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Server {

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    new Server();

}

public Server()
{
    try
    {
        ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(8000); //nieuw instantie van een ServerSocket

        System.out.println("Waiting for clients..");
        Socket socket = serverSocket.accept(); // lister for socket requests      



        while(true)
        {
            BufferedReader inputClient = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));

            DataOutputStream clientOutput = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());

            String clientInput = inputClient.readLine();

            System.out.println("Server: clientInput= : " + clientInput);

            InetAddress hostAddress = InetAddress.getByName(clientInput);
            String iPaddress = hostAddress.getHostAddress();

            System.out.println("Server: IP = : " + iPaddress);

            clientOutput.writeBytes(iPaddress);
            clientOutput.flush();

        }

    }
    catch(IOException ex)
    {
        System.err.println(ex);
    }   
}
}
```

CLIENT:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;


public class Client {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    new Client();   
}

public Client()
{
    try
    {
        Socket socket = new Socket("localhost", 8000);

        DataOutputStream toServer  = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());   
        BufferedReader fromServer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));

        toServer.writeBytes("google.com" + '\n');

        String ip = fromServer.readLine();
        System.out.println("Client: "+ ip);


    }

    catch(IOException ex)
    {
        System.err.println(ex);
    }
}

}
```

Comment: I execute the code and it give answer. Can i know what is the exact out put u looking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so after indexing the line with an '\n' and putting the line :
        Socket socket = serverSocket.accept(); 
inside the while loop in stead of inside try{} i got rid of all my problems.

Thanks, now i'll try to multithread this thing!

Answer (score 2):

When you start a client **and** a server program, they will have 2 separate consoles. Only one is visible at a time in the "Console" view of Eclipse. That is why you only see the server's.

You can switch between the active consoles with the "Display Selected Console" icon (it's a monitor icon) and also see the active console list.

Also you have a full-duplex connection. Both the client and the server can read/write. You use a `DataOutputStream` - `BufferedReader` representation for a one-way communication which is WRONG.

`DataOutputStream` writes binary data, `BufferedReader` reads text (character) data.

You should use one of the following pairings:

```
DataOutputStream - DataInputStream    and use writeUTF() and readUTF() methods
OR
PrintWriter      - BufferedReader     and use println() and readLine() methods
```

Comment: You have misunderstood the problem. He can see the output of client but not when server is running.

Answer (score 1):

```
   clientOutput.writeBytes(iPaddress);
   clientOutput.write("\n".getBytes());
   clientOutput.flush();
```

Just add these lines (second line) in your **Server** class.

**Reason**

In your **Client** class you are reading a line from buffer reader but you have not send any character from server indicating end of line. So in the second line we are writing new line character indicating end of line.

> When you close the server, connection get reset and available input are read. Thats why your Client prints if you close the server.

Optionally if you only want to modify your Client class you can write these lines

```
        char [] a = new char[100];
        int length = fromServer.read(a);
        System.out.println("Client: "+(new String(a)).substring(0,length));
```

Instead of these

```
        String ip = fromServer.readLine();
        System.out.println("Client: "+ ip);
```

Comment: Hey thank you so much for the reply. I added the clientOutput.write("\n".getBytes()); 
also adding a +'\n' after clientOutput.writeBytes(iPaddress +'\n'); did the same trick (i guess) But now it gives me an java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe. Also it seems like the server loops twice. First with input i've given, next with NULL.

Comment: No "\n".getBytes() and adding a+'\n' does not give the same result. Also check that you should wait for a connection inside while loop. Otherwise your server will only connect to one client. And consider accepting my answer if it helps.